# How to reuse the weights in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I will call the below tensorflow code for several times. Would the weights be reused or every time it will create a new graph?

```
    def lstm(encoder_cell, encoder_inputs_embedded, encoder_inputs_length):
        with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope_bilstm:
            ((encoder_fw_outputs,
              encoder_bw_outputs),
             (encoder_fw_state,
              encoder_bw_state)) = (
                tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=encoder_cell,
                                                cell_bw=encoder_cell,
                                                inputs=encoder_inputs_embedded,
                                                sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length,
                                                time_major=False,
                                                dtype=tf.float32)
                )

        encoder_outputs = tf.concat((encoder_fw_outputs, encoder_bw_outputs), 2)

        return encoder_outputs
```

Since I know it might not be reused, I tried the following code by adding an additional `reuse=True` in the `tf.variable_scope()`.

```
    def lstm(encoder_cell, encoder_inputs_embedded, encoder_inputs_length):
        with tf.variable_scope('lstm', reuse=True) as scope_bilstm:
            ((encoder_fw_outputs,
              encoder_bw_outputs),
             (encoder_fw_state,
              encoder_bw_state)) = (
                tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=encoder_cell,
                                                cell_bw=encoder_cell,
                                                inputs=encoder_inputs_embedded,
                                                sequence_length=encoder_inputs_length,
                                                time_major=False,
                                                dtype=tf.float32)
                )

        encoder_outputs = tf.concat((encoder_fw_outputs, encoder_bw_outputs), 2)

        return encoder_outputs
```

But I got the following error,

> ValueError: Variable inner/bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell/weights does
>   not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to
>   set reuse=None in VarScope?

How can I address this error? I really appreciate it!

What about `scope_bilstm.reuse_variables()`? I don't know where to insert that line in my program.

Comment: My understanding is that the first time the variable is defined, it should be in the scope without `reuse=True`. After the first initialization, the scope can be set to reuse by using `scope.reuse_variables()`.

Answer (score 0):

It may useful, look at [this](https://github.com/joelthchao/tensorflow-finetune-flickr-style/blob/master/network.py) in the `load_with_skip` function